# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in J:\xampp\htdocs\Website\rpg.php on line 157

Tags: php, mysql

im having trouble with this, this is my code

```
        ?php
      $db_host = 'localhost';
      $db_user = 'root';
      $db_pwd = 'password';
      $database = 'nzpcgames';
      $table = 'gameinfo';


@ $dbcon = mysql_pconnect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pwd);
      if (!$dbcon)
      {
        die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
        exit;
       }

mysql_select_db($database, $dbcon);

$query = "SELECT gameinfo.rank, gameinfo.game, gameinfo.platform, gameinfo.genre, gameinfo.publisher, gameinfo.developer, gameinfo.score*
FROM gameinfo
WHERE (((gameinfo.genre)='rpg'))";


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'No results were found';
    exit;
}

   ?>
```

though every time I try to excute it, i get the title error. On my tutorial power point it said to change $result, but it did not say what to, thanks for your help

Comment: Is that the whole script? Because you sure don't have 157 lines posted there. Unless your PHP is totally fubared, there's no way $result could be an array at that point. It'd be a boolean FALSE or a mysql result handle.

Comment: no the rest of the code is html from dreamweaver.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting ???

Comment: My guess is, he is over writing the $result in between the query and calculating the number of rows.

Answer (score -2):

may be it  is because you didn't put the connection,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}",$dbcon);
```

or you could try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name
```

check out this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: @mohamed: the connection is only required if you're keeping multiple connections open. otherwise PHP defaults to the last-opened one.

Comment: I know i thought this might be a problem anyways it's a good practice to put it in, right, sorry i am new to php thought i could help